# Regex in c# for digit with comma

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to use a RegEx in order to verify that an input is

empty -> to 100

exemple : 0 or 1 or 10,1 or 20.2 or 99

Only positive values, 0 or null value to 100, and accepting dot and comma.
Anyone could give me the right C# regex please ?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Can you expand upon examples by explicitly noting given input and expected output?

Comment: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet

Comment: True : 0 or 0,1 or 1 or 9 or 10 or 21,1 or 21.1 or 100

Comment: False : -1 or >100 (->101,etc...)

Answer (score 0):

Try this (if there is a comma or a period, at least one following digit is required):

```
^\d*(?:(?:\.|\,)\d+)?$
```

A great tool for these requests: http://regexpal.com/

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Lots of samples for numeric regex's can be found here

[Regex Lib](http://www.regexlib.com/?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

Answer (score 0):

Regex is about matching characters. It doesn't understand about numbers.

Try parsing it instead using `double.TryParse()`, and if that fails because the string has `,` as instead of `.`, replace `,` with `.` and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(100|\d{1,2}[.,]\d+)
```

But it's more correct to use `Double.Parse()` here.

```
string str = '10,1';
bool valid = false;
double num = -1;

str = str.Replace(",", ".");

if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str)) {
    valid = true;
} else {
    try {
        num = Double.Parse(str);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        valid = false;
    }

    if (num >= 0 && num <= 100) {
        valid = true;
    }
}
```

*Why didn't I use `Double.TryParse()` instead?

Sadly, failure to parse will make the outcome `0`, which falls to the valid condition.